# Array out of index when trying to read from a text file, and int32.tryparse

Tags: c#, arrays, file-io

I'm getting an error that says I have an array out of index, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I have commented out the line that Visual Studio has highlighted as the error. It happens in the `ReadData()` method. Thanks for any advice.

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Lab3.exe
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Lab3.exe
>   Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>   The program '[9140] Lab3.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

```
class Program
{
    private const int MAX_MEDIA_OBJECTS = 100; // Max number of array objects
    private int mediaCount = 0; // Counter to keep track of amount of media in Data.txt

    private Media[] media = new Media[MAX_MEDIA_OBJECTS];

    private Song[] songs = new Song[MAX_MEDIA_OBJECTS];
    private Movie[] movies = new Movie[MAX_MEDIA_OBJECTS];
    private Book[] books = new Book[MAX_MEDIA_OBJECTS];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program lab3 = new Program();

        bool didUserExit = false;

        int userSelectedOption;

        lab3.ReadData();

        do // Do While loop for the options menu, exits when the user selects the exit option.
        {
            lab3.DisplayOptions();
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            if (int.TryParse(userInput, out userSelectedOption))
            {
                lab3.ProcessSelectedInput(userSelectedOption, lab3);
            }
            else
            {
                lab3.DisplayErrorMessage();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();

        } while (!didUserExit);
    }

    public void ReadData()
    {
        // Opens the Data.txt file for read access
        FileStream mediaFile = new FileStream("Data.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader mediaData = new StreamReader(mediaFile);

        string mediaRow; // Holds each media data per row

        while ((mediaRow = mediaData.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Splits each row with the delimiter
            string[] mediaDataSplit = mediaRow.Split('|');

            // Temporary variables to hold media data
            int year;


            /** ERROR HAPPENS HERE ACCORDING TO VISUAL STUDIO IDE */
            bool didConvert = Int32.TryParse(mediaDataSplit[2].Trim(), out year);

            if (!didConvert)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Improperly formated field at line {0}", mediaCount + 1);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            if (didConvert)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("trace year {0}", mediaDataSplit[2]);
            }

            mediaCount++;
        }
    }

    public void ProcessSelectedInput(int userSelectedOption, Program labReference)
    {
        switch (userSelectedOption)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("case1");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("case2");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("case3");
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine("case4");
                break;
            case 5:
                Console.WriteLine("case5");
                break;
            case 6:
                Environment.Exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                labReference.DisplayErrorMessage();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void DisplayOptions()
    {
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("1. List All Books");
            Console.WriteLine("2. List All Movies");
            Console.WriteLine("3. List All Songs");
            Console.WriteLine("4. List All Media");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Search All Media by Title");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("6. Exit Program");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.Write("Enter choice: ");
    }

    public void DisplayErrorMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*** Invalid Choice - Try Again ***");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The question is not specific and give too little detail about where the error happens, please, at the very least include a stacktrace

Comment: You should really check the link that SLaks posted. If you can't debug a small and simple program then you have far more serious problems than an array being out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

The error is probably happening here: `mediaDataSplit[2]`

as a result from when you get it here: `string[] mediaDataSplit = mediaRow.Split('|');`

Whatever line it is looking at does not have as many "|" characters as you are expecting, so it is not creating as large of an array when it spits.

You should check what the value of `mediaRow` is when it is failing.

Answer (score 2):

`mediaDataSplit` contains less than three elements or it's empty. Before you try to access the third element you can check whether or not the element exists:

```
if(mediaDataSplit.Length >= 3)
    bool didConvert = Int32.TryParse(mediaDataSplit[2].Trim(), out year);
```